# C# DllIimport Unmanaged C code application (exe) file throw AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, marshalling, dllimport, unmanaged

I am currently working on exporting a few functions of a Win32 Application in order to call it from managed code and I am getting stuck on AccessViolationException. It is a very simple DllImport with simple types but as soon as I call function like malloc or printf inside unmanaged application it throws the exception.

Here is a sample of code :
//C# Program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  uint result = MyClass.ExecuteCommand((byte)10);
  Console.WriteLine(result);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

//C# Class library

```
public const string AppicationExe= "Application.exe";

[DllImport(AppicationExe, EntryPoint = "ExecuteCommand")]
public static extern UInt32 ExecuteCommand(byte mybyte);
```

// C Application

```
__declspec(dllexport) UINT32 __stdcall ExecuteCommand(unsigned char mybyte)
{ 
  printf("Why is it so difficult to make it works !!!!!!");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I use `/MT` to compile the Application.exe file and I can find msvcrt.dll when calling listDlls.exe from sysinternals

Comment: try to specify `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl`

Comment: Application.exe? Why not Dll? It is not trivial to call a function from .exe.

Comment: Pinvoking code in an EXE is not supported.  The C runtime isn't initialized and relocation doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

There is *very* little difference between a *managed* DLL and EXE.  You can rename the assembly of a class library to *.exe and your program still works.

That is however **not** the case for a C program.  An EXE is vastly different from a DLL.  For one, a C program requires that code always gets started at the main() function.  A requirement because before a C program can start running, the C runtime library must be initialized first.  The rough equivalent of the CLR having to be initialized before it can start executing managed code.  Skipping that initialization, like you do, is very likely to crash the program when it uses a C runtime function.  Like printf().

Entirely not an issue in managed code because the CLR always get initialized first before it executes a program.

Another very important detail is that an unmanaged EXE often is optimized by the linker, although that's disappearing.  An executable normally has a *relocation table*, a list of addresses that need to be adjusted when the program is loaded at an address different from its requested base address.  Always required for a DLL because the load address is not predictable, the address might already be in use.  Not required for an EXE because it always loads at a predictable address, so the linker strips that table to make the file smaller.  Kaboom if the program actually *does* get loaded at the wrong address, it always will when you pinvoke.

Entirely not an issue in managed code thanks to the jitter.

You will need to create a DLL instead.  Easy to do with the project wizard in Visual Studio.  Select the Win32 Project project template and select the "DLL" bullet for the Application Type setting at the next wizard step.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. You are right, even if I added DllMain in my Application, it is never called and as you said that 's why C runtime is not initialized.